# Copy multiple data frame rows down through sapply or lapply function instead of for loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr, lapply, sapply

I need to iterate through warehouse item data and paste that data repeatedly into specific months. In my real world application I'm going through 500k rows of data and my function takes 5 minutes to run, which just isn't practical.

I need a way to do the same thing with some sort of dplyr apply function, preferably sapply or anything that would output a data frame. Here is example data to show you the concept:

```
library(lubridate)  

# Item Data Frame
item.df <- data.frame(Item = c("A1","A2","A3","A4","A5"), 
        Gross_Profit = c(15,20,8,18,29),
        Launch_Date = c("2001-04-01","2001-04-05","2003-11-03","2015-02-
11","2017-06-15"))

# Months Data Frame
five.months <- seq(ymd(paste(year(today()),month(today()),1))-months(5),
                   ymd(paste(year(today()),month(today()),1))-months(1), 
                   by = "month")
five.months.df <- data.frame(Month_Floor = five.months)

# Function to copy Item Data for each Month
repeat.item <- function(char.item,frame.months){
               df.item = NULL

               for(i in 1:nrow(char.item)){
                  Item <- rep(char.item[i,1],nrow(frame.months))
                  Launch_Date <- rep(char.item[i,3],nrow(frame.months))
                  df.col = frame.months
                  df.col = cbind(df.col,Item, Launch_Date)    
                  df.item <- rbind(df.item, df.col) 
                  }  

               return(df.item)
               }
# Result
copied.df <- repeat.item(item.df,five.months.df)
```

Here are the variable results:

```
> item.df
Item Gross_Profit Launch_Date
1   A1           15  2001-04-01
2   A2           20  2001-04-05
3   A3            8  2003-11-03
4   A4           18  2015-02-11
5   A5           29  2017-06-15

> five.months.df
Month_Floor
1  2017-03-01
2  2017-04-01
3  2017-05-01
4  2017-06-01
5  2017-07-01

> copied.df
Month_Floor Item Launch_Date
1   2017-03-01   A1  2001-04-01
2   2017-04-01   A1  2001-04-01
3   2017-05-01   A1  2001-04-01
4   2017-06-01   A1  2001-04-01
5   2017-07-01   A1  2001-04-01
6   2017-03-01   A2  2001-04-05
7   2017-04-01   A2  2001-04-05
8   2017-05-01   A2  2001-04-05
9   2017-06-01   A2  2001-04-05
10  2017-07-01   A2  2001-04-05
11  2017-03-01   A3  2003-11-03
12  2017-04-01   A3  2003-11-03
13  2017-05-01   A3  2003-11-03
14  2017-06-01   A3  2003-11-03
15  2017-07-01   A3  2003-11-03
16  2017-03-01   A4  2015-02-11
17  2017-04-01   A4  2015-02-11
18  2017-05-01   A4  2015-02-11
19  2017-06-01   A4  2015-02-11
20  2017-07-01   A4  2015-02-11
21  2017-03-01   A5  2017-06-15
22  2017-04-01   A5  2017-06-15
23  2017-05-01   A5  2017-06-15
24  2017-06-01   A5  2017-06-15
25  2017-07-01   A5  2017-06-15
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use the built-in `merge` function:

```
copied.df = merge(five.months.df, item.df, by=NULL);
```

it achives a cross-join between the two data-frames. If you don't need all the columns (as your example shows) you can use `subset` before cross-joining (this should improve performance)

```
copied.df = merge(five.months.df, subset(item.df, select=c("Item", "Launch_Date")), by=NULL);
```

Comment: Worked like a charm @Bruno Zemengo. A lot easier than trying to run parallel processing...